# xparse: forward empty optional argument

Tags: tcolorbox, xparse

I'd like to use tcolorbox to call a theorem environment. My tcolorbox is supposed to ask for an optional title, and a mandatory label, so in the xparse specification I chose `O{}m`. Then, in the definition I use

```
before upper={\begin{thm}[#1]\label{#2}},
```

which works great when the title is defined... but unfortunately when no title are defined this fails with error

```
Undefined control sequence.
\ll@thm ...t \thmtformatoptarg {\thmt@shortoptarg 
                                              }\fi 
l.54 \begin{theorem}{thm:mygreatlabel}
```

I guess because the `thm` environment does not accept an empty optional argument like `\begin{thm}[] ... \end{thm}`. I tried to add conditions, but the brackets are considered as real characters, so I don't know how to solve this problem.

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools} %%
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\providecommand*\thmautorefname{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[thm]{Corollary}
\providecommand*\corollaryautorefname{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\providecommand*\lemmaautorefname{Lemma}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% \tcbset{customTheorem/.style={
% }

\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{theorem}{O{}m}{ %
    blank,
    breakable,
    before upper={\begin{thm}[#1]\label{#2}},
      after upper={\end{thm}{\itshape See \hyperref[proof:#1]{proof} on page~\pageref{proof@\thetcbcounter}}},
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=theorem-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\myproof{\thetcbcounter}{theorem-\thetcbcounter.tex}{#2}},
% #1
}


\NewTotalTColorBox{\myproof}{mmm}{ %
  blank,
  breakable,
  before upper={\begin{proof}[Proof of \autoref{#3}]\label{proof:#3}},
    after upper={\end{proof}},
  phantomlabel={proof@#1},
}{\input{#2}}

% \tcbset{no proof/.style={no recording,after upper=\end{thm}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Some theorems}

\tcbstartrecording % [theoremsamazing.records]

\begin{theorem}[My title]{thm:mygreatlabel}
  This theorem works
  \tcblower
  Proof is super obvious
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}{thm:mygreatlabel}
  This fails because the environment thm does not accept empty brackets.
  \tcblower
  Proof is not super obvious
\end{theorem}

See, I can refer to \autoref{thm:mygreatlabel}!

\lipsum[2]
\tcbstoprecording

\section{Some amazing theorems}

\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following definition of the theorem colorbox works:

```
\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{theorem}{om}{ %
    blank,
    breakable,
    IfNoValueTF={#1}{before upper={\begin{thm}\label{#2}}}{before upper={\begin{thm}[#1]\label{#2}}},
      after upper={\end{thm}{\itshape See \hyperref[proof:#1]{proof} on page~\pageref{proof@\thetcbcounter}}},
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=theorem-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\myproof{\thetcbcounter}{theorem-\thetcbcounter.tex}{#2}},
% #1
}
```

Here, instead of optional argument with empty fallback `O{}` the optional argument without fallback `o` is used an `IfNoValueTF` differentiates cases of argument and no argument.

Notice that `\begin{theorem}[]{label}...\end{theorem}` with explicitly given empty optional argument still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, it work! So it's not possible to "factor" it without rewriting two times before upper?

Comment: If it's possible then I don't know how, sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can I also ask you if you know how to test also if the comment is empty or not? Like `IfNoValueOrEmptyTF`, but all the functions I found needed backslash that seems to be not recognized...

Comment: Ok, I found the solution with `before upper=\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}{...}{...}`